# Gridlayout only adds elements vertically, not horizontally

Tags: java, grid-layout

I'm making a level editor for a simple game I'm creating, in the level editor I want to have a few buttons and labels that are aligned on a grid. Pretty much what gridlayout was designed to do.

The following code, for some unholy reason that is beyond me, only adds elements underneath each other, like this:

Map Width:

Map Height:

Map Depth:

it -should- look like this:

Map Width:   Map Height:

Map Depth:

I've been trying for an hour and I'm pretty much stumped, this should not take as much effort as it does to get it working, yet it does.

```
    private void drawUiElements()
{
    int xLoc = (int) (dim.width * 0.75);
    int yLoc = 0;
    int width = (int) (dim.width * 0.25);
    int height = dim.height;

    JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel();
    buttonContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(16, 2, 5, 5));
    buttonContainer.setBounds(xLoc, yLoc, width, height);
    buttonContainer.setName("buttonContainer");

    JLabel labelx = new JLabel("Map Width:");
    JLabel labely = new JLabel("Map Height:");
    JLabel labelz = new JLabel("Map Depth:");

    buttonContainer.add(labelx, "1");
    buttonContainer.add(labely, "2");
    buttonContainer.add(labelz, "3");

    add(buttonContainer);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add components to a specific cell when using `GridLayout`. You could set the initial number of rows to `0` so that the components are filled *rows-first*.

```
buttonContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5));
```

See: [How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Comment: But the api specifies that components are added row first, instead of column first. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ (figure 1)

Comment: This will only work if you specify an initial row count of `0` so that all possible rows are filled first before the layout is recalculated. See update